# хеш таблицы, добавление элемента методом chaining

Tags: python, хеширование

При добавлении элемента, кидает его во все списки из hash_table. Просидел в pythontutor где-то около часа, и не смог понять, почему во все, если я обращаюсь по индексу к списку из hash_table. Может мне нужен свежий взгляд...

```
class HashTable:
    def __init__(self, hash_type, values):
        self.hash_type = str(hash_type)
        self.hash_types = {'1': self.hash_type_1, '2': self.hash_type_2,
                       '3': self.hash_type_3, '4': self.hash_type_4, '5': self.hash_type_5}
        self.values = values
        self.hash_table = [LinkedList()] * len(self.values)*3
        print(self.hash_table)
        self.hash_types[self.hash_type]()

    def hash_type_1(self):
        for item in self.values:
            place = item % 12
            self.hash_table[place].add(item)

    def hash_type_2(self):
        pass

    def hash_type_3(self):
        pass

    def hash_type_4(self):
        pass

    def hash_type_5(self):
        pass

    def print_hash_table(self):
        print(self.hash_table)

    def __str__(self):
        str_1 = ''
        for items in self.hash_table:
            if len(items) != 0:
                for item in items:
                    str_1 += str(item)
                    str_1 += ' '
                str_1 += '\n'
        return str_1


class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.nxt = None
        self.data = data

    def __set__(self, value):
        self.nxt = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.data)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lst = list()
        self.index = 0

    def add(self, other):
        cur_node = Node(other)
        if len(self.lst) == 0:
        self.lst.append(cur_node)
        self.index = 0
    else:
        self.lst.append(Node(other))
        self.lst[self.index].nxt = cur_node.data
        self.index += 1

    def print_ll(self):
        for i in range(len(self.lst)):
            print(self.lst[i], ' ', self.lst[i].nxt, end='\n')

    def __str__(self):
        str_1 = ''
        for items in self.lst:
            str_1 += str(items.data) + ' ' + str(items.nxt) + '\n'
        return str_1

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.lst)

    def __iter__(self):
        for items in self.lst:
            yield items

    def __repr__(self):
        str_1 = ''
        for items in self.lst:
            str_1 += str(items)
            str_1 += ' '
        return str_1



Input: a = HashTable(1, [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 13])  
print(a)
Output:   
1 1 2 3 4 5 13 
1 1 2 3 4 5 13 
1 1 2 3 4 5 13 
1 1 2 3 4 5 13 
1 1 2 3 4 5 13 
1 1 2 3 4 5 13 
1 1 2 3 4 5 13 
1 1 2 3 4 5 13 
1 1 2 3 4 5 13 
1 1 2 3 4 5 13 
1 1 2 3 4 5 13 
1 1 2 3 4 5 13 
1 1 2 3 4 5 13 
1 1 2 3 4 5 13 
1 1 2 3 4 5 13 
1 1 2 3 4 5 13 
1 1 2 3 4 5 13 
1 1 2 3 4 5 13 
1 1 2 3 4 5 13 
1 1 2 3 4 5 13 
1 1 2 3 4 5 13
```

Comment: а как надо? а то не написать правильный код )

Comment: @VasylKolomiets забыл добавить, нужно что б додавало соответсвенно один елемент в список с нужным индексом, а не во все списки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените

```
self.hash_table = [LinkedList()] * len(self.values)*3
```

на

```
self.hash_table = [LinkedList() for i in range(len(self.values)*3)]
```

иначе вы создаёте всего один объект с кучей ссылок на него указывающиx. Можно проверить, что это в сущности один объект:

```
print(a.hash_table[0] is a.hash_table[1])
```